# AsyncTask and boolean variable

Tags: java, android

I'm really struggling with a simple issue that I'm hoping someone could assist in .

I have a basic application that authenticates to a database using a basic query.This query is run in the async doinbackground and returns a boolean named isSuccess.

It is then passed to a button onclick method that then determines if the user has entered the correct password. The boolean get reinitialized to true on the async method .

The problem I'm experiencing is that it seems like at the onclick stage it gets the initialised true boolean and not the changed variable value in the indobackground section.

```
    issueing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void  onClick(View v)
            {

                String passwordd = password.getText().toString();
                CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();// this is the Asynctask, which is used to process in background to reduce load on app process
                checkLogin.execute(passwordd,passwordd);
                password.getText().clear();

                if (checkLogin.isSuccess)

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Issue Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
     });
          }


 public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
     String z = "";
    boolean isSuccess = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r)
    {

          }

   @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... args)
    {

        String usernam = args[0];
        String passwordd = args[1];

        {
            try
            {

                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(db, un, pass);        // Connect to database
                if (con == null)
                {
                    z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                }
                else {



                    String query = " select   * from employee where password = '"+ passwordd+"'" ;
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                    String employee,pw;

                    if (rs.next()) {

                        employee= rs.getString("employee");
                        pw = rs.getString("password");
                        z = "Success";
                        //setSuccess(true);
                        isSuccess = true;

                   }

                    else if (!rs.next())
                         {
                        //setSuccess(false);
                             //setSuccess(false);
                             isSuccess = false;
                        z = "Invalid Password";

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                //setSuccess(false);
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

I'm suspecting that the onclick doesn't get the changed boolean value in time because of it running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because when you're using the following code:

```
CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
checkLogin.execute(passwordd,passwordd);
password.getText().clear();

if (checkLogin.isSuccess)
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Issue Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

you're thinking that the code is working in synchronous ways. `CheckLogin` is an AsyncTask which is working in a asynchronous way. So the CheckLogin code in the following code:

```
CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
checkLogin.execute(passwordd,passwordd);
```

will make a separate task and not blocking the process until it finished its job. So, Toast in your following code:

```
if (checkLogin.isSuccess)
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Issue Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

won't be executed because checkLogin.isSuccess is still false.

**The simple fixed** is by moving your check to `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
  if (checkLogin.isSuccess) {
    // do something with the success
  }

}
```

**The proper way** is by using a **listener** as a **callback** mechanism to tell the activity that the process is finished. This will separate your Activity and AsyncTask process to make it more maintainable in the future.

You can use an AsyncTask and callback with something like this:

```
public class CheckLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

  private String mUserName;
  private String mPassword;
  private ResultListener mListener;
  private String mMessage;

  public interface ResultListener {
    void onSuccess(String message);
    void onFailure(String message);
  }

  public CheckLoginTask(String userName, String password, ResultListener listener) {
    mUserName = userName;
    mPassword = password;
    mListener = listener;
  }

  @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {


    boolean isSuccess = false;

    // do some process with username and password

    // assume there is a a message
    mMessage = "Invalid password";

    return isSuccess;
  }

  @Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isSuccess) {
    if(isSuccess) {
      mListener.onSuccess(mMessage);
    } else {
      mListener.onFailure(mMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

that it can be used like this:

```
CheckLoginTask.ResultListener listener = new CheckLoginTask.ResultListener {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(String message) {
     // do something when success
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(String message) {
     // do something with failure
   }
};
CheckLoginTask checkLoginTask = new CheckLoginTask(userName, password, listener);
checkLoginTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

> For what i understand from your question, you want to check for
>   a password and then pass the result to the activity or somewhere else.

- I suggest implementing interfaces to make your code simpler and more effective.

since AsyncTasks run on a different thread, they have methods to contact with the main thread such as `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute(String r)` , so what you have to do is the following :

1. create an interface that would look like something like that :

   ```
   public interface PasswordChecker {
   void onChecked(Boolean isSuccess); 
   }
   ```
2. the second thing is to make your activity or class implement this interface, it would be this way :

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PasswordChecker {
   @Override
   public void onChecked(Boolean isSuccess) {
       if (isSuccess) {
         //Do Stuff with your isSuccess Boolean
       }         
   }
   }
   ```

or you can initialize a PasswordChecker object variable and pass it as an argument in the third step.

3. Make your AsyncTask require a PasswordChecker and then you must pass your activity or class, or object as an argument to the constructor, your AsyncTask would look like this :

   ```
   public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean> {

   private PasswordChecker checker;

   CheckLogin(PasswordChecker checker) {
       this.checker = checker;
   }

   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

       boolean isSuccess;

       //Do Your Work..
       //...
       //...
       //if (condition)
       isSuccess = true;

       return isSuccess;
   }


   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isSuccess) {
       super.onPostExecute(isSuccess);
       checker.onChecked(isSuccess);
   }
   ```

   }
4. Finally, you must initialize your AsyncTask using a PasswordChecker object as an argument :

   ```
   //Passing the activity it self (which implements PasswordChecker) as an argument
   final CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin(MyActivity.this);
   ```

   or

   ```
   //Or by passing a custom object
   PasswordChecker myChecker = new PasswordChecker() {
       @Override
       public void onChecked(Boolean isSuccess) {
           if (isSuccess) {
               Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this , "Login Success!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           else  {
               Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this , "Login Failed!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   };

   CheckLogin myCheckLogin = new CheckLogin(myChecker);

   //Do the rest of the job
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           //Execute your task
           checkLogin.execute("Username", "Password");
       }
   });
   ```

   - **Conclusion** : As you can see here, the result is passed through `onPostExecute(String r)`, your interface will be fired ( by `checker.onChecked(isSuccess);` ) every time `onPostExecute` is called, passing the boolean as an argument, and executes the code inside it depending on its value.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `doInBackground()` works an a different thread then your `onClick()`. `onClick()` works on the UIThread. so you don't recieve any updates to that thread.

First change your Async task declaration to this:

```
public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
```

The third parameter is the result parameter that is returned by doinbackground.

so your `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`will be something like this:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if(some_condition) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    // use the result
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    isSuccess = result;
};
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The main problem with the OP's code is that he does not know how an async task works.

Comment: you didn't even read the answer, you just downvoted it because I downvoted your answer. not cool man.